# Which attribute of the link element lets you specify the intended use of an external style sheet?

Tags: html, screen, stylesheet, media, rel

I believe the answer is `rel="stylesheet"` because it tells the `link` tag that the relation of this link is a stylesheet.

However, on a test, the answer was `media` (referring to `meda="screen"`).

Aren't I technically correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that the `rel` attribute (with the `stylesheet` value) is the correct answer, because the question asks about *the use* of a style sheet, so it’s already given that it’s a style sheet (which is what the `stylesheet` link type conveys).

Related attributes are:

- The [`rel` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel) conveys the relationship, depending on the value:

  - The [`stylesheet` link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-stylesheet) conveys the the linked resource is a **style sheet** for the document.
  - If the [`alternate` link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate) is provided in addition to `stylesheet`, it conveys that it’s an **alternative style sheet**.
- The [`title` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-style-title) gives the **style sheet name** of an alternative style sheet.
- The [`type` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-type) conveys which **styling language** the linked resource uses (i.e., its MIME type). If the attribute is not provided, `text/css` is assumed.
- The [`media` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-media) specifies for which environment / user agents the style sheet is intended.

I think it makes sense that the `media` attribute is the correct answer, because [media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-media-query) like `screen` or `print` convey a certain "use": use this style sheet for printing, use that style sheet for presentation on a screen.